# Refreshing AFOpenFlow

Tags: iphone, ipad, coverflow

I am creating a cover flow on iPad using AFOpenFlow library.

I am also providing a camera button in the view. If user captures any image and comes back to the previous view, the cover flow should be refreshed displaying the new image in it.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by Alastair Stuart is nice but if you have implemented coverflow already then you can reset/refresh the coverflow by calling as follows:

if you want to refresh or set the coverflow to index 0 you can use following:

`[(AFOpenFlowView*)coverFlow setSelectedCover:0 ];`

if you want to reset coverflow use:

```
    [(AFOpenFlowView*)coverFlow setNumberOfImages:0 ];
    //reset cover flow.
    [(AFOpenFlowView*)coverFlow setSelectedCover:(int)COVER_FLOW_RESET_INDEX ];
```

it will delete all the images in cover flow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) instead.